# ¿Cómo enviar datos al usar la función next con Express?

Tags: nodejs, express

Recientemente empecé a utilizar *NodeJS*, entonces me surge la pregunta, si quisiera pasar datos de mi función a otra para utilizarlos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Ejemplo:

```
function(req,res,next){
    //codigo 
    next();               
}
```

Ahora paso los datos hacia otro archivo con otra función:

```
function(req,res){
    //Se tratan los datos luego se devuelven al cliente 
}
```

¿Cómo puedo mantener los datos?

Comment: A parte de la respuesta de @amenadiel, en la documentación oficial en español lo explica muy bien: http://expressjs.com/es/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las funciones del tipo

```
function(req,res,next){
   //codigo 
   next();                 
}
```

Son `middleware`. Simplemente modifican algo en `req` o `res` y devuelven el control al flujo principal. No puedes pasar parámetros a través de `next()` pero **el contexto del request es el mismo para todos los middleware y para el closure final**.

Si quieres pasar un dato desde un middleware al closure final, puedes hacer:

```
function(req,res,next){
   req.mivariable = 'hola';
   next();                 
}
```

Y luego leerlo desde el closure que finalmente despacha la respuesta, ya que el contexto sigue siendo el mismo.

```
function(req,res){
  var mivariable = req.mivariable;
}
```

Comment: Sólo para precisar, el que no se pueda pasar parámetros es porque cualquier argumento que le pases a `next` se entiende que es un mensaje de error con el cual estás cortocircuitando la secuencia de middlewares